# Doesn't detect usb modem after kernel update

Tags: 10.04, modem, kernel

i'm a noob to Linux. Just installed Lucid Lynx a couple of days ago (through my flash drive) because i always wanted to use Linux in default. It was a clean install.

Now the next stop for me was to configure my internet. Its a usb modem (Netconnect Huwaei EC150) and my ISP is Reliance.
Although there was no installation package or anything supplied with the modem for Linux, i still googled my way through (and found a lot of people who had the same problem of connecting their Netconnect modems with Ubuntu and its derivatives) and installed:

- libuniconf4.6_4.6.1-1_i386
- libwvstreams4.6-base_4.6.1-1_i386
- wvdial_1.60.3_i386
- gnome-ppp_0.3.23-1_i386

in the same order and the modem started working after several 'Detect modem' and finding the suitable port for the ppp to dial the modem.

now i was happy but my Lucd used to freeze a lot too. So I Googled and a lot of people suggested that their issues were resolved after they updated the kernel. So did i but that's where it got jammed.

When i restarted it, there were 2 Linux kernel: .31 and .34 in the boot menu (i guess thats what GRUB is but anyway)
Now the .34 is running smooth but whenever i try to connect to the internet, it cannot detect the ttyUSB_utps_modem port through which it is supposed to dial but if i boot up with the Kernel version .31, its freezing but its connecting to the internet.

Please tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the Port has a new name nowadays...

Maybe `ls /dev/ttyUSB*` shows the new name... If you can't find a new port name post your dmesg output (type `dmesg > kernel.log` in a terminal) and paste that content to [the Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) service.

Answer (score 1):

open Synaptic Package Manager Type "Smartlink" into the search field in the Synaptic Package Manager and install all of smarlink package.

http://www.ehow.com/how_5435902_install-modem-drivers-ubuntu.html#ixzz2BcaT8Ean
it works with me very well

Answer (score 0):

What you basically have is a winmodem, even new laptops that embed
modems are attached to the USB bus.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DialupModemHowto

You may need to install sl-modem-daemon and sl-modem-source as well.
Follow the howto first, and if your modem doesn't show up, install
the two packages I mentioned, reboot, and try again.

See https://wiki.kubuntu.org/Outofthebox/Modem/Softmodem

for details on sl-modem. e.g. you could probe the modules instead or reboot.

This could be easier, it's not even mentioned in the official desktop documentation.